# Cannot download File in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, download, storage, local

I'm trying to download a file stored in my Larval 8 Storage folder. The path is correct I have checked it multiple times. And If I open the path in the search bar. It takes me to the needed image. What am I doing wrong here?

**Controller**

```
public function show($_id)
{
    $currentUrl = URL::current();
    $qrCode = QrCode::format('svg')->size(100)->generate($currentUrl."/".$_id);
    $path = storage_path('app/public/'.$_id.'.png');
    $asset = Asset::findorFail($_id);
    return view('assets::asset',compact('asset', 'qrCode', 'path'));
}
```

**asset.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{storage_path('app\public/'.$asset->_id.'.png')}}" download>{{$qrCode}}</a>
```

The path of the image is: file:///D:/Facility_Management_System/storage/app/public/6155a180001300004e005e22.png

Which is same path as `href="{{storage_path('app\public/'.$asset->_id.'.png')}}"`

But, When I click to download the file to download it does nothing.

Comment: What happens if you copy paste the link directly into the browser? does it open the file?

Comment: Yes, It does open it.

Comment: I'm not fully sure if you really want to provide the absolute file path here. In general you want the URL not the link the the file system when providing download. This might be the case in your code due to the usage of storage_path. Maybe this help
 the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls) make use of `Storage::url`instead.

Comment: I have tried that. Let me try again

Comment: Now it is downloading and the file name is the same.  But the extension is .htm  
This is the file i downloaded: 6155a180001300004e005e22.htm

Answer (score 0):

> The `download` attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

So in this case, if the downloaded file extension is `.htm`, it means that the response from specified link `{{storage_path('app\public/'.$asset->_id.'.png')}}` is html, instead of image file(maybe 404).

You need to fix the public url of the image file.

Comment: When I echo or dd(); or put this ``{{storage_path('app/public/'.$asset->_id.'.png')}}`` into a p tag. I get the desired result. With the .png ext. which is: file:///D:/Facility_Management_System/storage/app/public/6155a180001300004e005e22.png

Comment: You need to use public path of the image, like this `<a href="http://www.example.com/public/6155a180001300004e005e22.png">` instead of `<a href="file:///D:/Facility_Management_System/storage/app/public/6155a180001300004e005e22.png"`
If the image with public path will not be available, check the symbolic link.
`https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk`